# If there's another variable that controls whether heads outcomes are allowed, what distribution would that coin toss follow?

Tags: statistics, bivariate-distributions

For a usual coin with probability of heads $P(H)$, the distribution of the numbers of heads after $n$ tosses follows a binomial distribution. The coin can be biased or unbiased.

But suppose there's another variable, $\beta$, that controls whether heads outcomes are allowed to begin with. $\beta$ ranges from 0 to 1. $\beta = 0.6$ means 60% of the time, the outcome is forced to be not heads (i.e. tails) regardless of the natural outcome of the coin toss. $\beta = 0$ essentially means this factor is removed, coin can land either way naturally. $\beta = 1$ means 100% of the time, outcome is always tails.

What distribution would the numbers of heads after $n$ tosses follow, with respect to both the natural probability $P(H)$ and the control factor $\beta$?

Initially I thought it could be bivariate normal distribution, but that requires 2 independent variables, and I'm not sure $P(H)$ is independent of $\beta$ in this case.

Comment: Not sure the rules are clear.  Are you saying something like:  "We have a coin $C_1$ for which the probability of tossing $H$ is $p$.  We are also tossing a different coin $C_2$ for which the probability of throwing $H$ is $.6$ If $C_2$ comes up $H$ then we report $H$, regardless of the outcome of $C_1$.  If $C_2$ comes up $T$ then we report whatever the outcome of $C_1$ was. "

Comment: If so, that's just a binomial process.  The probability of reporting $H$ is just $\psi=.6\times 1+.4\times p$ (which is $p+.6(1-p)$ if you prefer that).

Comment: @lulu Probably too late too edit, but I think you intended to write 'If $C_2$ comes op $H$ then we report $T$, regardless of the outcome of $C_1$' (so $T$ instead of $H$, in this sentence, with the second sentence as is). I do believe that that is indeed what the OP is asking about.

Comment: @Vincent.  You are absolutely correct.  And that makes for a change in my computation of $\psi$, which I will leave to the OP.  It is still a binomial process, however.

Comment: @lulu Yes I think you roughly get the idea, but the probability of C2 getting $H$ is not a constant 0.6 like your formula suggests. It's also a variable like $p$. And I need to plot the distribution of $H$ from C1 with respect to both C1's $P(H)$ and C2's $P(H)$.

Comment: You wrote $.6$  ...  I was just following you.  Are you now saying that $C_2$ changes its probability every time?  Or are you just saying that you actually intended to write a variable like $\phi$ instead of a specific value like $.6$ but that it is the same $\phi$ for each toss?